# Problema de clave primaria multiple

Tags: base-de-datos, postgresql

Tengo la tabla en la cual se encuentran 2 campos como claves primarias

```
CREATE TABLE public.productounidad
(
prod_cod character varying(30) NOT NULL,
uni_nombre character varying(100) NOT NULL,
pu_cantidad numeric(8,2) DEFAULT 0,
pu_minimo numeric(8,2) DEFAULT 0,
pu_maximo numeric(8,2) DEFAULT 0,
pu_costo numeric(8,2) DEFAULT 0,
pu_precionormal numeric(8,2) DEFAULT 0,
pu_precioespecial numeric(8,2) DEFAULT 0,
CONSTRAINT productounidad_pkey PRIMARY KEY (prod_cod, uni_nombre),
CONSTRAINT productounidad_prod_cod_fkey FOREIGN KEY (prod_cod)
  REFERENCES public.producto (prod_cod) MATCH SIMPLE
  ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE NO ACTION,
CONSTRAINT productounidad_uni_nombre_fkey FOREIGN KEY (uni_nombre)
  REFERENCES public.unidad (uni_nombre) MATCH SIMPLE
  ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
```

y al referenciarlo en la siguiente tabla:

```
CREATE TABLE public.detalle
(
det_cod SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
det_cod_prod character varying(30),
det_nombre_uni character varying(100),
det_cod_doc integer,
det_fecha date NOT NULL,
det_descrip character varying(40),
det_cant integer,
det_ing_egr character(1),
det_prec_comp numeric(10,2) DEFAULT 0,
det_prec_comp_t numeric(10,2) DEFAULT 0,
det_prec_vent numeric(10,2) DEFAULT 0,
det_existencia integer,
det_costo_prom numeric(10,2),
det_prec_vent_t numeric(10,2) DEFAULT 0,
det_desc integer,

CONSTRAINT detalle_det_cod_doc_fkey FOREIGN KEY (det_cod_doc)
  REFERENCES public.documento (doc_cod) MATCH SIMPLE
  ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
CONSTRAINT detalle_det_cod_prod_fkey FOREIGN KEY (det_cod_prod)
  REFERENCES public.productounidad (prod_cod) MATCH SIMPLE
  ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
CONSTRAINT detalle_det_nombre_uni_fkey FOREIGN KEY (det_nombre_uni)
  REFERENCES public.productounidad (uni_nombre) MATCH SIMPLE
  ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
```

Me arroja el siguiente error :

no hay restricción unique que coincida con las columnas dadas en la tabla referida «productounidad»

Trate de añadir unique en la linea de primary key compuesta pero no me permite

Comment: te da en cual de los 3 constrains? y otra cosa, poner el nombre del producto como clave es una idea malisima!!! y si mañana cambia?? ya con el codigo deberia ser suficiente...

Comment: pero mando en los contraint on update cascade

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En este caso, me parece que tu intención es definir una clave foránea para la combinación de columnas `(det_cod_prod, det_nombre_uni)` que apunte a la llave primaria en la tabla `productounidad`.  Eso sí se puede hacer.

Pero por separado, tal como lo haces, no es válido, porque las columnas individuales no son únicas en la tabla `productounidad`.

Reemplaza las 2 claves foráneas con solamente esta:

```
CONSTRAINT detalle_det_cod_prod_nombre_uni_fkey FOREIGN KEY (det_cod_prod, det_nombre_uni)
  REFERENCES public.productounidad (prod_cod, det_nombre_uni) MATCH SIMPLE
  ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
```

Comment: gracias no sabia como hacerlo ya tenia un buen rato buscando la respuesta